# How to remove comma from last element of hash (from the loop)? perl

Tags: loops, perl, hash

Let's take an example code:

```
foreach my $cmp_id ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %totals )
{
    print $cmp_id . ", ";
}
```

How to get the last element of the hash printed without a comma? And if possible, without string operations (substring or something similar).

Comment: An alternative is: `my $pad = ""; foreach my $cmp_id (...) { print "$pad$cmp_id"; $pad = ", "; } print "\n"` where the post-loop newline is not in the original but likely to be needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unless you need to do something else, you're going a very long way around...

```
print join(", ", sort { $a <=> $b } keys %totals);
```

`join` concatenates an array using the delimiter given as the first argument, which is perfect for what you're after.

**UPDATE**

My solution does work, you need to provide more info in your question.

Add the keys to an array, and print them when you're done, i.e.:

```
my @keys;
foreach my $cmp_id (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %totals){
    push @keys, $cmp_id;
    ... other processing
}
print join(", ", @keys);
```

Comment: Yes, I do additional processing in loop, so your solution will not work.

Comment: Or do the additional processing with `map` - `print join ",", map {process $_} sort ...`

Comment: By default, `sort` does a stringwise sort.  The original code did a numeric sort.

Comment: @cjm, true. I've put that back.

Answer (score 0):

While I do prefer RET's original suggestion, worst case to drop off the ", " from the end of the string, use chop twice.

Or substr: $cmp_id = substr($cmp_id, 0, -2);